# Custom Message in docusign using XML tags using API

Tags: docusignapi

[image: 1]
Here i want to remove tat default tags that shows email address, name and default path..instead of this path add new custom message using tags in xml..pls help me

"Signature Request on Premier" +

"Dear TH, Testng docusing , BY THM " +
"sent"

Answer (score 0):

The email message itself is set by the emailBlurb line in the envelope definitions.

The structure of the message including the default sending email address, logos, and links, are all present in the Email Branding Resource file.

Customizing branding involves editing and uploading some very complicated XML files, DS recommends that the task be undertaken carefully as we do not support changing the messages for you. Additionally, not all plans have access to advanced resource branding, you'll need to check with your internal contact to find out.  We have some detailed guides on editing the branding files-- basically you're going to need to find the area that covers the HTML structure for the email message, customize it to your needs, then re-upload it.

Source: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-email-resource-file-v1-1